# Make image vertically seamless?

Tags: css, background, photo-editing, patterns

Any idea how make this image vertical seamless..I tried lot in ps..but no result..

[image]

or..tell me..where can I found this type of images(one side designed and seamless)?

Comment: This is a hard problem rather than a complex one.

Comment: Outside of just flipping another copy of it vertically (which would look bad, in my opinion), I'm not sure there is a simple answer.  If it's even possible, it's going to take a lot of manipulation.  You would be much better off finding one already intended for seamless use.

Comment: then tell me..where can I found this type of images(one side designed and seamless)?

Comment: I do not understand. What do you mean by "vertical seamless"?

Comment: i mean that i want to use as website background::
my css: backgroung-repeat: repeat-x;

Comment: the question is good, but i would do this in a 3d app as making it seamless would be easy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open image in Photoshop
2. Go to `Filters > Other > Offset`
3. Adjust vertical offset so that the image seam is in the middle of the image
4. Use the liquify tool to seamlessly connect the ribbons together
5. Fail miserably
6. Consider trimming all excess whitespace, and use `background-size: contain` instead

[More info on the background-size property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: At point 4 I suggest the shear tool. You'll find it under 'help' > Type 'shear'. Use it for the upper and lower half separately.

Comment: Alternative for point 6: Go to the market and by some ribbons; Point 7: Take a photo of ribbons that have repetition; Start at 1.

Comment: great help..any free source for this type of image(one side designed)ribbon or floral flower etc..

Comment: You could use the image you gave as example if you wanted to. `background-size: contain` makes sure your background image fits your element without stretching it. You can still position it to the left or right. Cut all excess white pixels (which will improve loading times) and place your ribbons anywhere you want using the `background-position` property.

Comment: o would copy the image on top of itself and offset till you find easiest seam location